# How many times I can make an "account merge request"?

Tags: support, accounts, merge-accounts

I have already made one *account merge request*, long back ago, and SO team merged the account successfully. For some reason, I wish to make the same request again.

So, the question is, Is there any *specific limit* to make [account merge requests](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)?

Comment: Well, one is too many.

Comment: depends on frequency I guess. Once every 6 to 8 years should be okay. Every 6 to 8 months ... really? Every 6 to 8 weeks ... what? Every 6 to 8 days ... Get out! Every 6 to 8 minutes .... suspension.

Comment: @rene I like that *"Get out!"* :)

Comment: I believe you can "do it yourself" by updating the email from your other account so they have the same email. See [By updating my job email settings, I have accidentally merged 2 accounts, how do I undo the merge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311629/by-updating-my-job-email-settings-i-have-accidentally-merged-2-accounts-how-do). If it was me though, I'd probably test it with something other than my high-reputation account first :) Note that the oldest account is considered the account to merge to.